# Generating ipa file ios on Ubuntu

Tags: ios, cordova, ubuntu, ipa

I am a beginner on iOS development. And I am following [this](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/04/23/phonegap-developer-app/) which seems to be great.

I have:

> 1. Ubuntu with phone gap installed
> 2. iPhone 5 for testing
> 3. Have installed phonegap in iPhone
> 4. Created a simple hello world using phone gap
> 5. The project pings and runs perfectly on my mobile (I think that is like emulator)

**What I want?**

Generate ipa file (like apk file in android I think) so that I can send that executable file to one of my friend for testing purpose.

**Question:**

How to create ipa file on Ubuntu using phone gap and where will that be located?

**Edit:**

As suggested [here](https://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/installing-iphone-apps-without-a-mac-using-apple-developer-account-and-phonegap-build-3/) (which is for Windows), is it compulsory to pay **$99** `to just test and distribute to my friends`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an IPA file using Ubuntu. You will need a Mac to create that file or use a cloud service like Phonegap Build.

Comment: Phonegap build will give me ipa file for free?

Comment: Yes, the free plan gives you 1 free private app. You will still need to pay Apple $99 in order to distribute the app to your friend to test.

Comment: So there is no way to test even one time without paying

Comment: If you had a Mac, you could sign with your Apple Id in xcode without paying, but without a Mac, you'll have to follow the instructions in the article you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need a MAC to build IPA. There are somethings that you can try if you are not a MAC user:

1. Asking your friends for MAC (Nah! not a preferred way)
2. Hiring an IOS app developer
3. Buying a MAC (If you have enough money RN in your hands :) )
4. Buying a MAC VPS server

The third option will be great. You can rent or buy a cloud MAC server from somewhere. They may cost $20 - $100 per month according to the system specs. You can search for them.